# C++ Queue Template STL

Tags: c++, templates, queue

I have the default constructor but the copy constructor I am having trouble with.  Any help.

```
enum Direction { front_to_back, back_to_front };

template <typename EType>
class Queue
{
  private:

    struct Node
    {
      EType Item;
      unsigned Priority;
      unsigned Identifier;
      Node * Pred;
      Node * Succ;
    };

    Node * Head;    // Pointer to head of chain (front)
    Node * Tail;    // Pointer to tail of chain (back)

  public:

    // Initialize pqueue to empty
    //
    Queue();

    // De-initialize pqueue
    //
    ~Queue();

    // Re-initialize pqueue to empty
    //
    void reset();

    // Initialize pqueue using existing pqueue
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with writing a copy constructor or you want to disable the copy constructor ?

Comment: What does this have to do with STL?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "trouble" you're having.

Comment: right now i am having trouble with the copy contstrutor.  I have figured out the destructor(original problem)

Comment: Is your plan to just ask a question for each method in the assignment here, showing no attempted code for the method you are asking about?  If so, that's not a very good plan.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335956/advice-on-implementing-put-function-in-a-c-templated-queue

Comment: No. In time I figured it out...then I stumbled. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are playing with raw pointers here you want to **disable** copy construction and assignment to avoid double-delete problems and memory leaks. This could be done either via:

```
private: // note that these are not implemented

    Queue( const Queue& );
    Queue& operator=( const Queue& );
```

or via inheriting from [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable).

Comment: Well Im not allowed to do that.  Wouldn't reseting do the same?

Comment: What do you think your copy construction/assignment should do? Full deep copy of the queue? Reference counting? What?

Comment: Confused myself meant the destructor.